# Obter retorno da palavra-chave que foi enviada para o Twitter Stream API na criação da topologia do Apache Storm

Tags: java, twitter-api, apache-storm

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que utiliza o Apache Storm integrado com a biblioteca Twitter4J, para processar *tweets* em tempo real. Porém estou com um problema: Existe alguma maneira de saber qual palavra-chave que deu origem aquele *tweet* retornado?

Exemplo:

```
//Palavras-chave para a criação da topologia do Storm
String keywords[] = {"Palavra 1", "Palavra 2"};

//Este método é chamado quando é retornado um tweet que contém aquela palavra-chave
  @Override
  public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
      Status status = (Status) tuple.getValueByField("tweet");
      System.out.println(status);
  }

//Resultado do Sysout
StatusJSONImpl{createdAt=Wed Sep 16 13:55:52 BRT 2015, id=645265788760587264, text='RT @user: Este é um tweet da Palavra 1' ... }

StatusJSONImpl{createdAt=Wed Sep 16 13:55:56 BRT 2015, id=645265788760587265, text='RT @user: Este é um tweet da Palavra 2' ... }
```

Tem algum modo de descobrir a palavra-chave que foi utilizada sem fazer um loop de comparação de string (como um *foreach*)?

Eu não encontrei qualquer atributo do objeto que tenha a palavra-chave, apenas os dados do *tweet*.